# Amazon SES issue on (sendmessage) line

Tags: c#

My code works fine except for the second to last line "client.Send(message);"

I have checked every variable and they all contain the right information.

I am throwing the exception immediately after the second line is processed

Error Message: "Object initialization can be simplified"

I'm using PORT 587

```
                using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
                {
                    //pass smtp credentials
                    client.Credentials =
                        new NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

                    //Enable SSL encryption
                    client.EnableSsl = true;

                    //Try to send the meessage. Show status in console.
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to send email...");
                        client.Send(message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Email sent!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Error messsage: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What is not fine with your second last line? Are you getting any error or something else?

Comment: I am throwing the exception immediately after the second line is processed

Comment: And what does the exception message say?

Comment: "Object initialization can be simplified"

Comment: That's not the exception. That's a Roslyn analyzer message.  (Note the *blue* icon, not a red one).

Comment: It is blue. That's the only message.

Comment: Look at what's written to the console. Or, put a breakpoint on the open curly brace after the `catch` and the put `ex.Message` in the Watch window. While you're at it, put a breakpoint on the close curly brace just before the `catch` keyword. You'll hit one or the other.

Comment: The server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. 

The only thing I can imagine is that my username is wrong, since I am using my full email... Is this correct?

Comment: I meant the error message is "The server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated"

Comment: I agree that it's something credential-related, since you're clearly setting `client.EnableSsl` to `true`. Whether it has to do with the format of the user name is something you'll need to examine further.